# How to write a program that asks the user how many Fibonacci numbers to generate and then generates them

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's what I have, I don't know what's wrong with it. It keeps saying that FibonacciArray[1] = 1 line has an error, "list assignment index out of range". Any help please! I'm trying to put the results into an array. For example, if the user inputs 4 as the number of fibonacci numbers to generate, I want it to put out 1 1 2 3 in the array.

```
amount = int(input("How many Fibonacci numbers would you like me to create?:"))
FibonacciArray = [amount]
FibonacciArray[0] = 1 #setting first two values of the array to 1
FibonacciArray[1] = 1
FibonacciCounter = 2

if amount == 1:
    print (FibonacciArray[0])
elif amount == 2 or amount > 2:
    print (FibonacciArray[0])
    print (FibonacciArray[1])
else:
    while amount > 0: #or while amount != 0
        #print out one fibonacci number
        FibonacciArray[2] = FibonacciArray[0] + FibonacciArray[1]
        print (FibonacciArray[2])
        amount = amount - 1 #decrementing amount  
        FibonacciArray[FibonacciCounter] = FibonacciArray[FibonacciCounter - 2] + FibonacciArray[FibonacciCounter - 1]
        print (FibonacciArray[FibonacciCounter])
        FibonacciCounter = FibonacciCounter + 1 #increment FibonacciCounter
        amount = amount - 1 #decrement amount again
        print (FibonacciArray)
```

Comment: You should read through the Python tutorial, it will solve these problems and more.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you think there is a flaw in the conditions you put in the loop.
The loop will only reach the third condition, i.e, the `else` part only if **`amount` is less than 1**.

```
if amount == 1:
    print (FibonacciArray[0])
elif amount == 2 or amount > 2:
    print (FibonacciArray[0])
    print (FibonacciArray[1])
else:
    while amount > 0:
        # Remaining code
```

---

I assume you are fairly new to the language and lot of your code seems **redundant** or of no use for the output.

```
FibonacciArray = [amount]
FibonacciArray[0] = 1 #setting first two values of the array to 1
FibonacciArray[1] = 1
```

The above will give you `IndexError` as you can assign values to existing index. You can replace those three lines with:

```
FibonacciArray = [1, 1]
```

So in order to add a new element to list, you can use `append()` method. The below is the pythonic alternative for your code.

```
FibonacciArray = []
FibonacciArray.append(1)
FibonacciArray.append(1)
```

---

In order to access last two elements from the list, you can simply use **negetive index**.

```
>>> array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> array[-1]
5
>>> array[-2]
4
```

So to find the new element in Fibonacci series, you could do,

```
FibonacciArray.append(FibonacciArray[-1] + FibonacciArray[-2])
print (FibonacciArray)
```

---

[Here](https://codeshare.io/2WRwbG) is link to the working code. Please look onto it, if you need help.

Comment: I'm lost on how to achieve what I'm going for.. looking forward to your help

Comment: @Ryan I would be happy to help! Please read the updated answer. Once again we can only give you hints, not the answer itself. Once we give the answer, it will deprecate the interest of learning new things on your side. So please have a look and reach out without any hesitation for help. :) Deal?

Answer (score 1):

```
FibonacciArray = [amount]
```

This doesn't make an array of length `amount`. It merely creates an array with one entry with the value of `amount`. What you are looking for is something like this:

```
FibonacciArray = [0]*amount
```

Second, IIRC, `else` cases only occur when every `if` and `elif` statement before it resolved to `False`. In this statement here:

```
elif amount == 2 or amount > 2:
```

You specify that `amount` must be greater than or equal to 2. This guarantees that your `else` block will **never execute.**

There are some more issues with your code, but those are the biggest offenders.

Your code should look something more like this:

```
amount = int(input("How many Fibonacci numbers would you like me to create?:"))
if (amount <= 0):
    print("Amount cannot be less than 1!")
else:
    FibonacciArray = [0]*amount
    FibonacciArray[0] = 1
    FibonacciCounter = 2
    if (amount > 1):
        FibonacciArray[1] = 1
    if (amount > 2):
        while FibonacciCounter < amount:
            FibonacciArray[FibonacciCounter] = FibonacciArray[FibonacciCounter - 2] + FibonacciArray[FibonacciCounter - 1]
            FibonacciCounter = FibonacciCounter + 1 #increment FibonacciCounter
    print(FibonacciArray)
```

EDIT: Added handling for negative numbers, and I realized I didn't handle the case `amount == 1` right. Fixed it.

Comment: Alex, Isn't it better to lead them to the answer, rather than giving the code as a whole of what they wanted?

Comment: I wanted to do that too, but I felt that there were too many things wrong with the original. I apologize if that isn't what I am supposed to do; this is my first post.

Comment: No problems. I just mentioned FYI. While writing next answer try to guide them to answer rather than giving out the ouput.

Comment: I will say that from the comments the OP left, he was getting more confused with the technical clarifications. Maybe he does need to just see working code. It has always helped me.

Comment: Ah, I think I can understand what needed to be done a bit better now. My code was really all over the place, thanks for this Alex I'll study it!

Comment: No problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah! Looks he has no clue. It's better you helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you create your array you could set it like this:

```
FibonacciArray = [None] * amount
```

This will fix your error and set 'amount' number of array values to None.
But there are further errors in your code. The while loop will not be called unless the number entered is 0 because your else condition will catch any number greater than 2 first.

Comment: What's the simplest way to get this done? I've been trying for a while and I really have no clue